# Rows of Change of Basis Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Maybe a stupid question, but since I don't find a confirmation to my doubt on the Internet, I'll also ask here.

To change basis from $A$ to $B$ we use a matrix whose columns are the basis vectors of $A$ expressed in the new basis $B$. But we can also say that its rows are the basis vectors of $B$ expressed in the old basis $A$, can't we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's not in general true. If it were, then the change-of-basis matrix from $B$ to $A$ would be the transpose of the c-o-b matrix from $A$ to $B$. It's not, in general. Instead, it's the *inverse* of that matrix.

If the change of basis matrix is *orthogonal*, then the inverse is the transpose, in which case your statement about the rows is correct.

Comment: So we can say it's true only with basis systems constituted by orthogonal vectors, right?

Comment: Close. It's only true when the change-of-basis is an orthonormal matrix. That can happen even with non-orthogonal bases (example: if $A$ and $B$ are the same basis, then the change-of-basis matrix is the identity, regardless of whether they're orthogonal bases).  Answer edited accordingly.